# Printing `NSRect` argument passed to Cocoa method in lldb

Tags: debugging, cocoa, lldb, arm64, calling-convention

In order to debug a macOS program I need to print the `NSRect` that is passed to [-[NSView:setNeedsDisplayInRect:]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483475-setneedsdisplayinrect). I can set a breakpoint in that method, but I have trouble printing its argument.

`NSRect` is “essentially” a struct of four `double`s. In order to demonstrate the problem I have written a small self-contained program. It is compiled with Xcode 12.5 and run on a Mac mini with M1 processor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
} MyRect1;

typedef struct {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    long d;
} MyRect2;

void foo(MyRect1 rect) {
    printf("%f\n", rect.a);
}

void bar(MyRect2 rect) {
    printf("%f\n", rect.a);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MyRect1 rect1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    MyRect2 rect2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    foo(rect1);
    bar(rect2);
    return 0;
}
```

The [Procedure Call Standard for the ARM 64-bit Architecture (AArch64)](https://c9x.me/compile/bib/abi-arm64.pdf) states that

> If the argument type is a Composite Type that is larger than 16 bytes, then the argument is copied to memory allocated by the caller and the argument is replaced by a pointer to the copy.

Therefore I would expect that both `foo()` and `bar()` are called with a pointer to the structure as the single argument. Setting a breakpoint in `bar()` and casting the first argument to `MyRect2 *` indeed produces the expected result:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100003e94 argtest2`bar(rect=(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)) at main.c:22:29
    frame #1: 0x0000000100003f34 argtest2`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdff428) at main.c:29:9
    frame #2: 0x000000019871d430 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
(lldb) expr -- *(MyRect2 *)$arg1
(MyRect2) $0 = (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)
```

However, this does not work with `MyRect1` in `foo()`:

```
lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100003e64 argtest2`foo(rect=(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)) at main.c:18:29
    frame #1: 0x0000000100003f1c argtest2`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdff428) at main.c:28:9
    frame #2: 0x000000019871d430 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
(lldb) expr -- *(MyRect1 *)$arg1
error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory
```

Note that both structs have the same size (32 bytes), and differ only in the last member.

*Question:* How can I print the argument passed to a function in lldb if that argument is of type `NSRect` (or any other struct of four doubles)?

Comment: I can see in the assembly that `MyRect1` is being passed in `d0` through `d3`, but I don't know why. Apple has [their own additions to the ABI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-arm64-code-for-apple-platforms), but I see nothing about 32-byte structs and floating-point registers.

Comment: @Siguza: That is extremely helpful. `register read d0 d1 d2 d3` does indeed print the correct values of the `MyRect1`, and that works for `NSRect` as well. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with the ARM(64) architecture and calling conventions. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching the double for the long in your structure was actually significant.  A struct of four doubles is a Homogeneous Floating-point Aggregate, whereas the struct of three doubles and a long is a Composite Type, and they have different passing rules.  The former is passed in the floating point registers if it fits (as you have found), whereas the latter is passed on the stack.

BTW, if you want to read the values passed into a function for which you don't have debug information, it's best to stop before the "function prologue" has been executed. The function prologue (especially in optimized code) will often copy registers from their original locations, and reuse them, so the register state after the prologue will no longer reflect the calling conventions.

However, debug information for functions is generally not accurate during the prologue.  There's no technical reason why it can't be, but no compilers I know of track the prologue, and unless you are actually debugging the compiler output that region of code isn't terribly interesting. So for code with debug information it's more convenient to stop after the prologue is executed, and that's the lldb default.

To switch that default, add `--skip-prologue 0` to your `break set` command.

Comment: Thank you very much. So what I missed are the rules *“B.2: If the argument type is an HFA or an HVA, then the argument is used unmodified.”* and *“C.2: If the argument is an HFA or an HVA and ..., then the argument is allocated to SIMD and Floating-point Registers ...”*

Comment: Are the “convenience variables” $arg1, $arg2, ... of any use in such a case?

Comment: No.  The $argN variables are really just aliases for the argument passing GP registers.  They don't claim any knowledge of the actual function's signature.